# Understanding a quick SOCKS proxy

Tags: ubuntu, socks

### Synopsis

Essentially I would like to set-up a proxy for `YIM!`.  The reason for this is my office is within a shared office block with other companies, thus meaning the main office is blocking certain connections.

Instead of going to the MD and going through the paper-work, I thought I could create a SOCKS proxy.  My problem is that, regardless of what i've done the connection is still not working.

### Set-up

I have my local machine running `ssh -D 10001 myserv` *(Where `myserv` is configured as a host inside `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` only defining the `hostname`)*

> localhost: Ubuntu Desktop 13.04
>
> myserv:    Ubuntu Server 10.11

I've installed pidgin and configured it to use a SOCKS proxy.  The configuration is set to:

> Host: localhost
>
> Port: 10001
>
> User:
>
> Password:

I have provided no credentials which didn't work, I then provided them and still no luck.

1. My first question is what is the difference between SOCKS, SOCKS4 and SOCKS5?
2. In regards to my firewall, do I need to open any outgoing ports on my `localhost`, or `myserv`?

Answer (score 0):

SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 are different versions of the protocol, with SOCKS5 supporting UDP and authentication. Use it if possible.

In your setup, `myserv` needs to be able to make arbitrary outgoing connections.

To debug, run your ssh command to myserv with `-v`. You should then see connection attempts in your SSH session:

```
$ debug1: Connection to port 10001 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 10001 for 66.254.109.60 port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 50699 to 127.0.0.1 port 10001, nchannels 4
```